# Contact Form php, js, and jquery issues

Tags: php, javascript, contact-form

My contact form is not working and I cant find the bug at all.

I have `contact-us.php` and `sendmail.php` and `custom.js`

Contact-us.php, has an include call to sendmail.php.

Also being honest with you I have included this script located at js/jquery.min.js but not sure if its related.

The contact form is working at http://www.completeoffice.co.uk/contact.php

but not at:

The contact form is located: dev.madhousecreative.co.uk/contact-us.php.

Youll see when you click send it does nothing. It doesnt send the email or say thank you. Its meant to send the email and give a message saying thank you etc.

**Edit:**

After suggestions in the answers i changed the name values in the input fields and the contact form and it now sends the email to my email address from the contact form, however, it will only send the email if all the fields are inputted correctly, i.e. numbers in the phone number field, correct email address etc. Which means its validating the form. if you dont input details correctly, it just doesnt send the email and refreshes the page, and nothing else happens. its meant to give details of errors of input to inform the user.

Also, if the email sends, the page just refreshes also, its not meant to do that, its just meant to give a thank you message as you can see at the bottom of the php code above.

so the email is sending if inputted right, and its validating but not outputting any messages to the user and is refreshing the page instead.

EDIT 2: AFTER COMMENTS I ADDED OTHER SCRIPTS CHANGED LINES In HEAD SECTION. DOESNT REFRESH ANYMORE. READ COMMENTS FOR FULL UPDATE

Comment: dev.madhousecreative.co.uk/contact-us.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot to include `jQuery` sources. Firebug gives error `jQuery is not defined`.

**EDIT**

Instead of

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="custom.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

write

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="custom.js"></script>
```

Comment: include `jQuery` source **before** including `custom.js`. check my edited answer.

Comment: when I do that the contact form does even send the email. It doesn't refresh or do anything.

Comment: meant to say doesnt even send the email

Comment: You can't expect jQuery-based validation in `custom.js` to work if you don't include jQuery before including `custom.js`

Comment: your page reloads after submitting because you use `submit` input type - learn about ajax, write proper javascript function that will send the data to server asynchronously and launch it on button click

Comment: thats not the problem because I have it on another site where it works  and is set up the same. check http://www.completeoffice.co.uk/contact.php

Comment: on the second link you provided there is a line: `<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>`. there is no such line on the page where the problem exists.

Comment: you added it in the wrong place - change 2 lines from your code into the lines I posted in my edited answer

Comment: right ive done that and also got rid of   '<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>' after them two lines. If you go to my contact form now, its just doesnt do anything, not even refresh

Comment: firebug shows that all of your input tags are outside `<form>` - you just create form tag and close it. fix this.

Comment: huh in my code I have <form blabla> all the tags and then closed </form>

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/8508/discussion-between-h4b0-and-ryan-murphy)

Answer (score 0):

I think the source that h4b0 meant that you must include is the jQuery source script. Example:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your form has a small issue you have email as a field NAME twice.

```
                       <div>
                                <td><label>Email*</label></td>
                               <td> <input name="email" value="" id="email" class="input1" size="80" type="text"  /></td>
                            </div></tr>
                            <tr>

                            <div>
                                <td><label>Phone Number*</label></td>
                               <td> <input name="email" value="" id="email" class="input1" size="80" type="text"  /></td>
                            </div></tr>
                         <tr>
```

According to my debugger you have a lot of files that do not even exist:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined
GET http://dev.madhousecreative.co.uk/jqtransformplugin/jqtransform.css 404 (Not Found)
GET http://dev.madhousecreative.co.uk/formValidator/validationEngine.jquery.css 404 (Not Found)
GET http://dev.madhousecreative.co.uk/jqtransformplugin/jquery.jqtransform.js 404 (Not Found)
GET http://dev.madhousecreative.co.uk/formValidator/jquery.validationEngine.js 404 (Not Found)
```

Comment: Right. the actual contact form sends me a message now. It doesnt do the jquery validation bit though or thank you message